# Yeoman: use Bower-defined dependency in controllers and test

Tags: yeoman, bower

I have added a dependency to the bower.json and I would like to use it in a angularJs service or controller.

When I use the library inside a web page, everything works correctly because the dependencies are loaded first. This is not the case when I am running unit tests, where dependencies results in an undefined object and my test fails.

How can I import bower-defined dependencies in an angularJs controller for testing purpose?

Comment: I'm having same problem with `angular-animate` causing my unit tests to fail.  I did `bower install angular-animate --save` too.

Comment: The last time I had a look into it, there was no integration between bower and grunt, which I used for running my tests. How do you run your unit tests?

Comment: I run unit tests using Karma and Jasmine.  I believe I solved my issue in my QA.  Had to specify which version of `angular-animate` to install. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944883/unable-to-find-a-suitable-version-for-angular-with-bower-installation-error-for

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you need to execute:

```
bower install yourdep --save
```

Otherwise it won't be saved in the bower.json.