# Unable to find a suitable version for angular with bower installation error for angular-animate module

Tags: angularjs, bower, ng-animate, yeoman-generator, karma-jasmine

I am using `Angular 1.2.6`. I am trying to use bower to install [angular-animate](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-animation.html) and [ngAnimate-animate.css](https://github.com/yearofmoo/ngAnimate-animate.css).  I've tried installing (`bower install --save angular-animate`), uninstalling several time and diff code on github from 1.2.16 and 1.2.17.

Bower keeps wanting to install the older version of `angular-animate 1.2.16` compatible with `Angular 2.1.12`.

All of my passing karma unit tests fail after installing `angular-animate` as well.

**I keep on getting this error.  Any ideas why?**

```
bower angular-animate#*         cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.2.16
bower angular-animate#*       validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#*
bower angular#1.2.16            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower angular#1.2.16          validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower angular#>=1               cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.16
bower angular#>=1             validate 1.2.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.2.6 which resolved to 1.2.6 and is required by angular-cookies#1.2.6, angular-mocks#1.2.6, angular-resource#1.2.6, angular-route#1.2.6, angular-sanitize#1.2.6, angular-scenario#1.2.6, temp
    2) angular#1.2.16 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-animate#1.2.16
    3) angular#>=1 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-bootstrap#0.10.0

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

[?] Answer:
```

I have entered `!1` and `!3` before with no success.

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.6",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.6",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.6",
    "angular-route": "1.2.6",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.10.0",
    "angular-toggle-switch": "~0.3.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.16",
    "ngAnimate-animate.css": "~0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.6",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": ">=1"
  }
}
```

[Related question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921594/angularjs-error-module-nganimate-is-not-available)

[Angular moved angular-animate out of core to it's own dependency in v1.2](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two part solution

1. [ngAnimate-animate](https://github.com/yearofmoo/ngAnimate-animate.css) has a js file, `app/bower_components/ngAnimate-animate.css/animate.js` that needs to be added to `files:` in `karma.conf.js`
2. `bower info angular-animate` and install the version specific to your angular version.  In this case, `bower install angular-animate#1.2.6 --save`